# How should I setup the File Sharing to access Works Files from Home PC (VPN is ok)

Tags: mount, samba, file-sharing

I have a work computer which is running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm wondering what method is best for me to be able to view it's files from home. I will be accessing the files at my workplace through a VPN so firewall issues are not a problem in this case.

I would like to be able to have it appear as though I have all my works computers files, but at home. I need to do some development using IDE's from home and it is essential that I am able to navigate to the directory for the sake of the IDE.

I've heard of Samba shares. Is this a good choice, or are there better options out there? If Samba share suits what I want to do I thought the following guide on the Ubuntu Forums would be ideal:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=288534

Edit: Home computer will be using Ubuntu 12.04 as well and the VPN aspect of this is already setup and working. This is a matter of how the sharing should be done.

Comment: How about a free-of-charge private repository, say git or mercurial at bitbucket.org? I understand that you need primarily source code stuff.

Comment: @user68186 I edited in some more information. I do not want to use a solution such as Dropbox as I want full access to the whole system as if I was root, not just certain files.

Comment: @moon.musick Yes, most is code, and yes a repo is being used, however full access to the PC's files is ideal.

Comment: I have not done this. Hence, I am not putting this as an answer. I think you should try Network File System (NSF) rather than Samba share. NSF is a Linux (Ubuntu) native solution, while samba works connecting Windows to Ubuntu. See [the How to setup NSF in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

Comment: NFS is very nice in some situations, very inconvenient in others. In some setups only a full reboot may close a failing NFS connection. People use also WebDAV a lot and generally it works, only with HTTPS on weaker machines (CPU-wise) it's a resource hog (at least I couldn't manage to optimize it enough). In my home setup I use `autofs` with NFS and I guess it might work in OP's situation. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Comment: @user68186 I don't want to be bound to Ubuntu though.

Comment: @Fogest NFS works with virtually any *nix, so it is not Ubuntu-exclusive.

Comment: In my view samba doesn't keep the file ownership and permission in order. But this may be the limitation of NTFS as well. Try out a few of the solutions others have suggested and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `sshfs` is a good idea. I use it often for a secure / encrypted link to my NAS server when I am at the workplace, for various stuff, including listening to music stored on the remote server.

`sudo apt-get install sshfs` for the client side should be just enough. For the server side you might go with the default setup of `openssh-server` (or change most stuff, whatever works for you).

Basically, you just mount a remote dir in local dir, just as with `mount` command.

```
sshfs user@server:/remote/dir /local/dir [-p non_standard_port]
```

As it is a user-controlled mount, unmount it with `fusermount -u /local/dir`.

It is secure and simple. You may set up `/etc/fstab` with `sshfs` too.

Some more info [in here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS).

Comment: How does sshfs handle connection loss? Say I lose connection for a few seconds, how does it handle it?

Comment: See this answer http://serverfault.com/questions/306796/sshfs-problem-when-losing-connection and also http://www.johnhawthorn.com/2011/04/prevent-hanging-sshfs-connections/ (two somewhat opposite approaches).

Comment: Also, it is so easy to setup you might just try it and see. I haven't measured it in any way, but with proper keepalive it just does not disconnect on the link I am using it with. Not trying to bash other answers, but Samba sharing with proper authentication is real PITA. I have anonymous (only firewall-limited) Samba sharing enabled in my NAS (my wife clings to her Win XP as if her life depended on it) and it works well enough, but I tried to set up something much more complicated at my workplace (legacy accounting app) and totally gave up after a few wasted days.

Comment: Where should I be mounting this to? I'm a new to mounting things, and I'm not exactly sure where to mount this? I tried mounting it in media by doing `sshfs username@host.ca:/ /media/Mount`. I see the mount however there is nothing in it.

Comment: Also when trying to unmount using the command you give I get the following error: `fusermount: entry for /media/Mount not found in /etc/mtab`

Comment: Okay, I was able to mount a directory. How do I mount so that I have access to the whole file system? My account has sudo privileges.

Comment: @Fogest try [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/158392/how-do-i-sudo-over-sshfs). `fusermount` most likely didn't work because the mount didn't succeed, so there was nothing to unmount.

Answer (score 1):

## SSH

I would suggest git, but since you want access to all the files you might also want to try SSH.

### Advantageous over Samba

1. I have found samba to be slow at times.
2. At times editing a file is not possible because of the permission setup being wrong.
3. Connection is encrypted.

### Work computer setup

You simple install an ssh server on the work computer. Openssh will work which you can install using

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

### Home computer

On the home computer go to nautilus, click file -> Connect to Server and choose SSH as service type. In server put the IP (or alais) address of the work computer, port should be 22, root folder ('/') for folder is fine and in user name the name of the user for the work computer (root is **NOT** recommended).

I don't have a 12.04 install so there might also be a password field to fill in (can't remember if 12.04's nautilus has one).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the remote folders will not be accessible from the **File>Open** and other dialog boxes inside any applications such as an IDE, like @Foqest wants. The remote folders need to be mounted in the local system, not just accessible from a **Bookmark** in Nautilus.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have 12.04 handy. It definitely works in Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is a SAMBA/CIFS or NFS fileshare server for your work computer. If the VPN connection is sometimes down, then maybe SAMBA is the better choice.

NFS require the connection to be always up, to be able to have it mounted all the time on your home computer. But you can have your home directory unified at work and at home if you want.

If you have a mixed environment with linux, windows and mac then Samba is more supported.

So here is what i did to make it work:

> sudo apt-get install samba

and to configure with a gui:

> sudo apt-get install system-config-samba

and then applying my changes:

> sudo smbd reload

This is my research, I only tried Samba myself:

[Guide to setting up NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)

[Guide to setting up Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide)